# Can't change Internet Explorer Properties security level for internet zone on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

**On Internet Explorer Properties dialog, security level slider bar for internet zone is grayed out.  Why?**

[image: Internet Properties dialog]

*(It seems to be stuck on the default level)*

Comment: I don't think High is the "default" default level for the Internet zone so it looks to me like this is being set via GPO. Is the computer this is running on joined to a Windows AD domain?

Comment: @Joe: This PC is not on a domain, Active Directory or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

A PC also has Local Policies. See [here](http://archive.sembee.info/windows/policy.asp) on how to change them. Though I don't know which one would block that specific slider.